# How to Update attribute values from queried features on SimpleFeatureCollection?

Tags: geotools

**We want to update some features of a Layer. We have used the following Code to update features but not successful.**

Firstly Get SimpleFeatureSource by a Feature Layer.

`SimpleFeatureSource sfSource = (SimpleFeatureSource) Lyr.getFeatureSource();`

After quried on it we got some data in the form of SimpleFeatureCollection.

```
org.opengis.filter.Filter flt = ff.within(ff.property("the_geom"),ff.literal(polygon));
SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = sfSource.getFeatures(flt);
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = sfc.getFeatures().features();          
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next(); 
   feature.setAttribute(0, object);
}
```

If we do this feature's attribute will update and reflect in **sfc** (SimpleFeatureCollection) but not reflect in **sfSource** (SimpleFeatureSource).

Updated:-

```
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("Transaction");
    Maplayer MpLayer = this._MapListLayers.get(cmbLayers.getSelectedItem().toString());
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
    Filter flt = ff.id(ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44177"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44178"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44179"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44180"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44181"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44182"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44183"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44184"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44185"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44186"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44187"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44188"),
            ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44189"), ff.featureId("long cl0805143437.44190"));
    try {
        MpLayer._SimpleStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        MpLayer._SimpleStore.modifyFeatures("Equipment", new String("Equipment"), flt);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();
    }
```

As per your comments we have tried upper code but results me in an error shown below:-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: OGR Error: General Error
>       at org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.Layer_SetFeature(Native Method)
>       at org.gdal.ogr.Layer.SetFeature(Layer.java:145)
>       at OgrSource.JniOGR.LayerSetFeature(JniOGR.java:284)
>       at OgrSource.OGRDirectFeatureWriter.write(OGRDirectFeatureWriter.java:114)
>       at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:337)
>       at org.geotools.data.store.DiffTransactionState.commit(DiffTransactionState.java:161)

Answer (score 2):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.org) uses a [streaming feature source](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/featuresource.html) methodology, so whenever you ask the `FeatureSource` for new features it rereads the `Datastore`. This is especially important if you are using a filter or all sorts of surprises may occur.

If you want to modify a feature permanently you need to use a `FeatureStore` and call the [`modifyFeatures` method](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/FeatureStore.html#modifyFeatures-org.opengis.feature.type.Name-java.lang.Object-org.opengis.filter.Filter-). So your example above will become something like:

```
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("Example1");
SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) sfSource;
store.setTransaction( transaction );

Filter flt = ff.within(ff.property("the_geom"),ff.literal(polygon));

SimpleFeatureType featureType = store.getSchema();
try {
   store.modifyFeatures( "0", object, filter );
   transaction.commit();
}
catch( Exception eek){
   transaction.rollback();
}
```

Comment: **After Apply upper code following error will generate:-**
ERROR 6: SetFeature() must be used on a feature with a FID.
java.lang.RuntimeException: OGR Error: General Error
       at org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.Layer_SetFeature(Native Method)
       at org.gdal.ogr.Layer.SetFeature(Layer.java:145)
       at org.geotools.data.ogr.jni.JniOGR.LayerSetFeature(JniOGR.java:287)
       at org.geotools.data.ogr.OGRDirectFeatureWriter.write(OGRDirectFeatureWriter.java:137)
       at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:337)

Comment: Does your feature have a fid?

Comment: That doesn't actually verify anything, check for null

Comment: Yes each feature has FeatureID. Verified by following Code :-

`simplefeature.getIdentifier();`

Comment: I have checked thoroughly but i didnt find any null values in ID attribute.

Comment: please check my updated question , we have tried with FID also.